# размер TextBox под содержимое

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Пытаюсь сделать контрол для ввода времени.

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="0.5"
        BorderBrush="Black" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Column="0"                         
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Text="{Binding Time.Hour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:TimeBehavior/>
                </ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text=":" 
                       Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                     BorderThickness="0">
                <ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:TimeBehavior/>
                </ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text=":"
                       Grid.Column="3"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="4"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     >
                <ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:TimeBehavior/>
                </ia:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы размер TextBox был равным размеру под двузначное число. Ограничить в xaml не могу, так как шрифт может быть разным.
Пробовал в TimeBehavior написать  следующее

```
 private void associatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = AssociatedObject.Text;
        if (AssociatedObject.Text.Length < MaxChar)
        {                
            AssociatedObject.Text = "99";                
        }
        AssociatedObject.MinWidth = AssociatedObject.ActualWidth;
        AssociatedObject.MaxWidth = AssociatedObject.ActualWidth;
        AssociatedObject.Text = text;
    }
```

Но это не сработало. Дайте наводку, как это можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот просто

```xml
<TextBox Margin="5"
         Text="{Binding Minutes, StringFormat=D2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>
```

Свойство

```cs
private int _minutes;
public int Minutes
{
    get => _minutes;
    set
    {
        if (value > 59)
            _minutes = 59;
        else if (value < 0)
            _minutes = 0;
        else
            _minutes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Обработчик

```cs
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.Width = textBox.ActualWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так проблему с обновлением ActualWidth решил. После задания текста надо вызвать UpdateLayout(). Но теперь другая проблема - у Border  не отрисовывается правая сторона.